# Testing Carrierwave Uploads with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minitest

Just trying to add some basic tests to my Carrierwave Uploader.  I am starting with the default generated tests and trying to go from there.  I am getting a weird error and not sure where to go from here.

I have a polymorphic `Upload` model which has:

```
mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
```

My DocumentUploader has something like this:

```
  def store_dir

    "#{model.uploadable_type.downcase.pluralize.underscore}/#{model.parent_asset.id}/uploads/#{model.id}/"

  end
```

This makes my store directories look like:

/locations/24/uploads/56

when I run the default tests for example:

```
  test "should destroy upload" do
    assert_difference('Upload.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @upload
    end

    assert_redirected_to uploads_path
  end
```

I get:

```
ERROR["test_should_destroy_upload", UploadsControllerTest,1.9893769259997498]
test_should_destroy_upload#UploadsControllerTest (1.99s)
NoMethodError: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
            app/uploaders/document_uploader.rb:34:in `store_dir'
```

In my Uploads fixtures I have the polymorphic associates set etc.  The`model` is not being set to the Uploadable association in the DocumentUploader i.e. it's nil.

All my other tests work so far and my uploader works fine in production and development etc.  I am sure I am missing something trivial in the set-up or it's a Carrierwave specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in really late here.

Using `fog` with carrierwave I have found to be a drag.  `carrierwave-aws` gem is non-negotiable for me.

The [Read Me](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-aws) provides a quick, overall stub to add to the `uploads.rb` configuration file:

```
config.aws_credentials = {
  [...], # Required
  stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? # Optional, avoid hitting S3 actual during tests
}
```

For the presentation layer, I find this acceptable because, you often want to see results, and particularly the versions of such results.  Once those run properly, they are hard to break if the method does not change - and those are rather static methods.

Comment: I agree - I ditched fog soon after this.